# Search Cursor to count not null values records?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, error-999999, null

I am trying to achieve print all featureclass, total count, notNullvalues. I am trying hard on this code.

but getting Error:

suggest how can I code better and working. I am not regular python user.

`RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.`

```
import arcpy
import arcpy
import collections

arcpy.env.workspace = r"path"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#time.sleep(5)

#StartTime = time.clock()

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*Rebok*")
for fc in fclist:

   fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

   Tcount = str(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc))


# Loop through Table and see which fields are NOT NULL or Non Blank
   cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
   count = 0
   for row in cur:
    if not row.getValue(fields) in [None, " ", ""]:
            count += 1
   print count
```

Comment: arcpy.GetCount_management takes Layer or View as argument, not FeatureClass. row.getValue takes single field as argument, not list.

Comment: @SergeNorin I am using FGDB that has multiple FCs with lots of fields(different data type)  some field contains "", " ", NULL. so that I am trying this method. I am skeptical about `Getcount` management with what SQL will Suit.

Comment: What is the full error message, including line number, that you receive when you run precisely the code that you have presented?

Comment: @GISDataButcher you can use FGDB, shapefile or whatsoever, but GetCount works with Layer object. Run `MakeFeatureLayer_mamagement` first with your FC as input If you want to use it. And fields. Replace `if not row.getValue(fields) in [None, " ", ""]:` with `if not set([row.getValue(f) for f in fields]).intersection(set[None, '', ' ']):`

Answer (score 2):

To get a count of null values, use the `where` argument for GetCount, e.g.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("MyFeatureclass", "test_lyr", r"Fieldname is null")
print arcpy.GetCount_management("test_lyr")
```

If you need to test for other 'empty' values too, change the where argument to `Fieldname is null OR Fieldname in ('', ' ')` etcetera.

In general this will be faster than using a cursor.

Comment: Getting this Error `ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression OBJECTID is null  OR OBJECTID in ('', ' ')
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).` ..I thing it caused due to multiple data type in multiple fields. for Example the above one fails because it is numeric type. (taken objectid as example, have others numeric fields too)

Comment: Of course, objectid is a numeric field, so it can never be `''` or `' '` (a string). Moreover, I don't think the objectid field can ever be empty, so why check for that?

Comment: Okay. this was good. I skipped Objectid in Loop for that matter. But How do I do for numeric fields?

Comment: The same, but without single quotes. E.g. `"FieldName is null"` to check for an empty value or, `"FieldName = 0"` to check for a value of zero, if that's what you want.